# Keep UL > LI content inline

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm struggling at the moment to create a horizontal unordered list using HTML and css. Ideally, I would be able to add other elements within each line and it would maintain its *horizontalness.*

Here is the css/html I am currently working with:

```css
.map-sub-container {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
.map-sub-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.map-sub-nav > li {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-sub-container">
  <ul class="map-sub-nav">
    <li>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>I am a paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h1>Goodbye</h1>
        <p>I am a paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Am I going about this completely wrong? Is it not possible to nest additional elements in a `<li>` element and continue to display `inline`? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you forgot to float left.

Comment: Just add to li **display: inline-block;**. Regards.

Comment: @Milan - I'm an idiot. That was it and discovered it independently moments before you posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.map-sub-container {
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
.map-sub-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.map-sub-nav > li {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
  posistion:relative;
  float:left;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-sub-container">
  <ul class="map-sub-nav">
    <li>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>I am a paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <h1>Goodbye</h1>
        <p>I am a paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this answer works, so I will accept it. `Inline-Block` resolved my issue without having to set a width (probably specific to my purposes) - or float. Thank you.